# Screen showing vertical coloured lines and is not responding to touch

Tags: screen

I have an Infinix Zero 5, and its screen has stopped working. It is just displaying multi-coloured vertical lines and is not responding to any touch. The power and volume buttons of the phone are still functional, the fingerprint scanner still works (as the display turns on when it is scanned) and the display even dims when the phone reaches the display timeout.

The phone hasn't been dropped or anything, and the screen initially appeared after taking it out of my pocket. When I restarted the phone the first time (by holding down the power button), it started working again, but now even when restarting the phone, the display still shows these lines. I know the phone is still in working order as off and on the phone vibrates for notifications.

Is this a display issue for which I have to replace the screen or is there some other problem with the phone?

[image: Phone with broken screen]

Answer (score 0):

first of all, force reboot your device by holding

while it reboots, if the infinix logo appears without those lines, then thats a software issue and if you see lines there too, then time to get a new display